# LoadError for dotenv/load while Dotenv.load works

Tags: ruby

I want to use `dotenv` in pure ruby environments. I mean I'm not using `Rails`.

The github instruction says there are two ways for loading the variables.

```
require 'dotenv/load'

# or
require 'dotenv'
Dotenv.load
```

In my environments the latter way works, but `require 'dotenv/load' raises the this error:

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- dotenv/load
```

I gonna use `Dotenv.load` if former way doesn't work, but I want to know the reason of the error.

I'm using `ruby 2.3.3p222` and `dotenv (2.1.1)`.
What am I doing wrong?

#### Additional Info

I'm using `bundle exec pry` and `load 'myapp.rb'.
When I load the script I get the error.

Comment: are you using bundler?  If so, can you please load your app with `bundle exec ruby myapp.rb` and tell me if that solves the issue?

Comment: I'm using `bundle exec pry` and `load 'myapp.rb'. When I load the script I get the error.

Comment: Try `pry` and then `require 'dotenv/load'`. It should return `true`. If you still get the error then your Ruby environment is screwed up.

Comment: Also note that `require 'dotenv/load'` will do [the exact same thing you're doing manually.](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv/blob/master/lib/dotenv/load.rb)

Comment: why are you using `pry` like this?

Comment: Have you tried loading the gem first using bundler or require ‘dotevn’ then require ‘dotenv/load’? It may be that the gem isn’t loaded for you to look in the ‘load’ path

Comment: @anothermh I see. The file is created from `2.1.2` or `2.2.0`. Thanks for the link. https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv/commit/3641eca91974181ce4d76a209bf54a0f053988f0

Comment: Did you add dotenv in to Gemfile ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'dotenv/load' is implemented from `2.1.2` or `2.2.0`.

To upgrade the `dotenv` gem is needed.

Answer (score 4):

```
gem install dotenv
```

Tested on version dotenv-2.7.5